# Fetch the publisher's prefix in dynamics 365 plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, publisher

I am writing a plugin for dynamics to store some records in a custom entity/table. Now the problem is every custom entity/table you create in the dynamics environment is assigned a publisher prefix in its `LogicalName` and schema name even its attributes have the prefix. Now when a certain event is triggered in the system the plugin stores some information in this table but i don't know what the prefix is.

PROBLEM:
How can I fetch the publisher prefix inside the plugin dynamically?

I can hardcode the name of the table in the plugin but the prefix needs to be fetched dynamically.

I can just fetch all entities and then filter out the table I created, but I believe that will be heavily taxing on the dynamics system.

Well I do have oauth access to the dynamics CRM. Can I store the prefix in the dynamics system somewhere probably as a name of the entity then dynamically fetch it in the plugin?

Comment: thanks @Brian Tomposett. I will make sure to do proper formatting and use valid grammar next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I managed to finally figure out how to fetch the prefix and this is how, I am assuming the plugin was registered in the active solutions.

1. Fetch your registered plugin by querying the `pluginassembly` table using `QueryExpression`.
2. Extract the `solutionId` from the plugin info.
3. Fetch the solution by `solutionId` and that's how you get the `publisherId` associated with the solution and then use that to fetch the prefix. The property is called `customizationprefix`.

The sample code is as follows,

```
 QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
 {
     EntityName = "pluginassembly",
     ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("solutionid"),
     Criteria = new FilterExpression()
 };

 query.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, "pluginName");

 var pluginInfo = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

 solutionId = pluginInfo.Entities[0].Attributes["solutionid"].ToString();
 var solutionEntity = service.Retrieve("solution", Guid.Parse(solutionId), new ColumnSet(true));

 EntityReference publisherAttr = (EntityReference)solutionEntity.Attributes["publisherid"];
 var publisher = service.Retrieve("publisher", publisherAttr.Id, new ColumnSet(true));
 
 string publisherPrefix = publisher.Attributes["customizationprefix"].ToString();
```

I understand that the code is poorly written because I am not a .Net dev but it does the job ;).

Answer (score 0):

Plugins are attached to a message to a specific table (for example create of `account` or update of `myprefix_customtable`)

Inside the plugin you can check the table that triggered the event by extracting the `LogicalName` of the `Entity` or `EntityReference` (`EntityReference` you have inside the Delete message)

However you have no direct information on the publisher (or the solution) from a plugin. You can query `publisher` and `solution` tables, but that has nearly nothing to do on which message and field your plugin has been triggered.

Comment: i see what you mean. The thing is that my plugin is tracking export to excel events and the Entities that have this are business entities(Leads, accounts etc) whose LogicalName doesn't have the publishers' prefix. Are we on the same page? Thank you so much for the support.

Comment: As I wrote your plugin more than checking on which table is running doesn't give you additional info, you need to query for extra info